# Zipaligner not found in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, zipalign

According to this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/manually-signing-the-apk zipaligner is supposed to come with Android SDK, but it is not there. Is my Visual Studio bugged, or I need to install it manually? Keytool works fine, but not in package manager console, so I assumed zipaligner should be there too.

Answer (score 2):

`zipalign` comes with Android SDK, you can find it under the `build-tools` folder. 
 If it's not there you can either reinstall the `build-tools` version that you need or the whole Android SDK.